# Nonexistent parameter in Swiftmailer

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

In an attempt to configure both a memory & a spool mailer in a Symfony 4.3 application I followed the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html#spool) to create this configuration:

```
swiftmailer:
    default_mailer: memory
    mailers:
        memory:
            sender_address: 'admin@bogus.info'
            transport:        smtp
            username:         admin@bogus.info
            password:         123Abcd
            host:             localhost
            spool: { type: 'memory' }

        spooler:
                sender_address: 'admin@bogus.info'
                transport:        smtp
                username:         admin@bogus.info
                password:         123Abcd
                host:             localhost
                spool:
                    type: file
                    path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/spool'
```

And in services.yaml:

```
    App\Services\Emailer:
        $spoolMailer: '%swiftmailer.mailer.spooler%'
        $defaultMailer: '%swiftmailer.default_mailer%'
        $senderAddress: '%swiftmailer.mailer.memory_mailer.sender_address%'
        $projectDir: '%kernel.project_dir%'
```

But with those four parameters in the service the following occurs with `php bin/console debug:container`:

> The service "App\Services\Emailer" has a dependency on a non-existent
>   parameter "swiftmailer.mailer.spooler"...

Why does this configuration not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The service "App\Services\Emailer" has a dependency on a non-existent parameter "swiftmailer.mailer.spooler"...

Surrounding parameters with the `%` symbol allows you to pass **values** to your services.

As you want to inject a **service**, you should prefix your parameter with the `@` symbol.

Also, to get the default mailer service, you have to inject `@swiftmailer.mailer`

**EDIT:** Proper way to retrieve the sender address: `%swiftmailer.mailer.memory.sender_address%`

---

**Updated service definition :**

```
App\Services\Emailer:
  $spoolMailer:   '@swiftmailer.mailer.spooler'
  $defaultMailer: '@swiftmailer.mailer'
  $senderAddress: '%swiftmailer.mailer.memory.sender_address%'
  $projectDir:    '%kernel.project_dir%'
```

Comment: You're right about the missing `@` - I missed that. Unfortunately, after adding them I still don't pass `debug:container`, although the response is just `Did you mean this: "swiftmailer.mailers"?`

Comment: I just double checked, it seems that the exception is coming from the `$senderAddress` parameter. The good parameter to inject should be `%swiftmailer.mailer.memory.sender_address%`.

Comment: Pasting your code over mine worked best! Many thanks.